# Можно ли держать статичным ApplicationContext?

Tags: android, context

Если держать `Context` статичным, то IDE предупреждает об утечке памяти, так как контекст привязан к активности. А если держать статичным `ApplicationContext`?

```
public static Context context; //memory leak
```

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/memoryleak.php - там просто четко описаны типовые утечки и способы борьбы с ними

Comment: IDE предупреждает об утечке, т.к. она не знает, какой это именно `context`. 
`Application` или обычный.
`ApplicationContext` можно держать без рисков утечек памяти (можете проверить сами с помощью `LeakCanary`).
Но, с точки зрения архитектуры, гораздо чище инжектить его с помощью `Dagger2`.

Comment: А зачем держать `ApplicationContext`, если он и так доступен практически отовсюду?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja например в `MVP` или `Clean Architecture`

Comment: @no news, я правильно понял, что в MVP или CA это полезно, так как классы не должны быть связаны с андроид-классами?

Comment: Полностью разделить Android и Java классы  не получится, т.к. тот же `applicationContext`  относится к `Android`, но нам нужно часто его использовать например в том же  `Repository`(CA) (например, при получении координат пользователя и с помощью `GoogleApiClient`

Данные паттерны(`MVP` и `CA`) необходимы, чтобы писать хороший и тестируемый код, и чтобы приложение было легко расширяемым в дальнейшем

Comment: Я бы сказал так: если для того, чтобы все было по фэншую (то есть по MVP/CA) нужно держать статический `ApplicationContext` - значить фтопку такой фэншуй или вы не понимаете ваш фэншуй :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationContext` не хранит ссылку на `Activity` и живёт на протяжении   всего срока жизненного цикла приложения.

Обычный `Context` привязан к конкретной `Activity`, и если его сделать статичным, это приведёт к утечке памяти.

Возможно, это ошибка при проектировании самого `Android SDK`. (Т.к. сущность по сути одна и та же)

`Android Studio` помечает данный фрагмент кода как утечку памяти, потому что по умолчанию думает, что это `context` от `Activity`.

**Итог:**

1. Если сделать статичным `ApplicationContext`, утечки памяти не будет. Можете проверить этот момент с помощью [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).
2. С точки зрения архитектуры, гораздо чище инжектить `ApplicationContext` с помощью [Dagger2](https://google.github.io/dagger/) и не делать его статичным.

Comment: Спасибо. Ух уж этот Dagger я смотрю популярный и с ним проще. Но я уже сколько раз перечитал его документацию и ничего не понимаю :)

Comment: Это нормальный процесс) Поверьте, так у большинства)

Comment: Большинство кто его используют могут не понимать, и это нетолько про Даггер . И совет про Context,  очень плох. Я могу сходу сделать сценарий, где вы словите экзпшн при статичном App, уже не говоря - если вы не крутанете лупер от него, и будете продолжать плодить хендлеры, для грязных нужд. Конечно можно навернуть классический синглтон, но ради чего? Если получается так что грязные руки лезут туда где нужен контекст, поверьте самый худший вариант, если у вас будет статичная ссылка, потом проект разрастается и будет столько неявных вызовов, никогда такой код не протестируется. И это факт.